# WCF library host in Windows service returns error

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, wcf-library

I'm new with WCF services, I have a **WCF library** (DLL) hosted in Windows service, this service is called by a DLL which is being called by reflection, I have the following app.config in Windows service and the EXE that calls the whole things together:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IVerifyIC" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/S3IcVerification/S3.IcVerfication.Wcf.Service/VerifyIC/"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IVerifyIC"
          contract="VerifyIcService.IVerifyIC" name="WSHttpBinding_IVerifyIC">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

when I run in deployment environment, it gives me an error message:

> Service 'S3.IcVerfication.Wcf.Service.VerifyIC' has zero application
>   (non-infrastructure) endpoints.

It's also doesn't work on WCFTestClient.
Which returns an error message describing that there is no endpoints... etc

What did I do wrong?

Comment: As the message says: there are no endpoints.
Probably it's not the client-side configuration which has this error, but the server-side.. on server side, the the client section is wrong - there has to be a service section.

Comment: So how should I alter this config file?

Comment: You should use two different config files: MyServiceApp.config and MyClientApp.Config. The server config is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731303.aspx and should be pretty the same as your client-endpoint config.